# SQL Server user-defined-function using WITH, IF together

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

I need to create a scalar-valued `user defined function` in `SQL Server`. I need to have `with` clause to store some intermediary tables which will produce the final return result. I also need `IF .. ELSE` because depending on the input parameter the query to the resutl is different. However, I can't write the code without error combinaing these two elements together. My function would be like this:

```
             CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getMyValue](
               @inputType int      
               )
            RETURNS float
        AS
        BEGIN       

        DECLARE @result float
        ;

         WITH tempTable AS
            (
                SELECT * from TableA          
            )
              ;

           IF inputType = 1
           set @result = select sum(t.result1) from tempTable
           else 
           selecset @result = select sum(t.result2) from tempTable   
           return @result
        END
        GO
```

But now it complains `incorrect syntax near 'if'`. If I remove the `with` clause (and query against some actual table) it compiles, or if I remove `IF` statements it also compiles. So how can I make them work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `IF` like this in the context of an SQL query. Try using the following instead:

```
DECLARE @result float, @result1 float, @result2 float

WITH tempTable AS
(
   SELECT * from TableA          
)
SELECT @result1 = sum(case when @inputType = 1 then t.result1 else 0 end), 
       @result2 = sum(case when @inputType = 2 then t.result2 else 0 end)
FROM tempTable

IF @inputType = 1
   SET @result = @result1
ELSE 
   SET @result = @result2

RETURN @result
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I saw in some other posts saying "can't use `IF` in a query" but it never occured to me that it applies to me. (I thought my usage of  `if` is for flow control not `INSIDE` query). Anyway, it works now.